# AngularJs my View is not loading

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


  $stateProvider


    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })



  .state('notePadHome', {
    url: '/notePadHome',
    views: {
      'notePadHome': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/notePadHome.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/notePadHome');

});
```

Comment: did you have error in console ? in the console you can see if the path to the view is correct and loaded

Comment: no there is not any error.

Comment: what did you try ? what the url of the view who's not rendering

Comment: notePadHome is not rendering,DashCtrl is already their in controller.js and i created notePadHome.html under templates folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tabs.html you need to apply at **ion-nav-view** element the name="tab".

And then in your app.js try this:

```
.state('notePadHome', {
url: '/notePadHome',
views: {
  'tab': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/notePadHome.html',
    controller: 'DashCtrl'
  }
}
})
```

If you want remove the tab from app.js, remember to remove it also in your home view route, like this:

```
.state('notePadHome', {
 url: '/notePadHome',
 templateUrl: 'templates/notePadHome.html',
 controller: 'DashCtrl'

})
```

Comment: cant I completely remove the tab from app.js?And then use ion-nav-view in notepadHome.thml

Comment: Yes if you need the menu only in your home you can do this.

Comment: can you briefly explain whats the use of views their ,it would be great help

Comment: Abstract states could contain other states, but they can't be activated directly. They are typically used for the menu. For more information see this: http://mcgivery.com/understanding-ionics-side-menu/